# Jensen inequality about mapping

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, inequality

In $X \in L_{p}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P).$
If $p \in [1,+\infty]$, then why the map $x \mapsto |x|^p$ is convex, and we can apply Jensen's Inequality?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version of [Holder's](https://brilliant.org/wiki/holders-inequality/) inequality says:

$$a_1^{\lambda_1}b_1^{\lambda_2}+a_2^{\lambda_1}b_2^{\lambda_2}\le(a_1+a_2)^{\lambda_1}(b_1+b_2)^{\lambda_2}$$

where $\lambda_1+\lambda_2=1$. Let $\lambda_1+\lambda_2=1$.

$$\begin{split}|tx+(1-t)y|&\le t|x|+(1-t)|y|\text{ triangle inequality}\\
&=t^{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}|x|^{\lambda_2/\lambda_2}+(1-t)^{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}|y|^{\lambda_2/\lambda_2}\text{exponents are 1}\\
&=t^{\lambda_1}t^{\lambda_2}(|x|^{1/\lambda_2})^{\lambda_2}+(1-t)^{\lambda_1}(1-t)^{\lambda_2}(|y|^{1/\lambda_2})^{\lambda_2}\text{rewrite some terms}\\
&=t^{\lambda_1}(t|x|^{1/\lambda_2})^{\lambda_2}+(1-t)^{\lambda_1}((1-t)|y|^{1/\lambda_2})^{\lambda_2}\text{group terms}\\
&\le \underbrace{(t+1-t)^{\lambda_1}}_{=1}(t|x|^{1/\lambda_2}+(1-t)|y|^{1/\lambda_2})^{\lambda_2}\text{Holder's inequality}\end{split}$$

with $a_1=t_1, b_1=1-t, a_2=t|x|^{1/\lambda_2}, b_2=(1-t)|y|^{1/\lambda_2}$. Let $\frac 1 {\lambda_2}=p,p\in[1,\infty)$. Then

$$\begin{split}|tx+(1-t)y|^{1/\lambda_2}&\le t|x|^{1/\lambda_2}+(1-t)|y|^{1/\lambda_2}\\
|tx+(1-t)y|^{p}&\le t|x|^{p}+(1-t)|y|^{p}\end{split}$$

Hence $f(x)=|x|^p$ is convex. Since it is convex, you can apply Jensens inequality to it.

Comment: can you please explain the line with the "group terms" ?

Comment: It is just algebra because $\lambda_1+\lambda_2=1$ so you can raise any variable to $\lambda_1+\lambda_2$ since its to the power of 1. I made some changes to the post and it might be clearer

Comment: I am confused now more in the new line.Because $(x^{\lambda_1})^{\lambda_2}=x^{\lambda_1 * \lambda_2}$

Comment: You are right- thanks for catching. I edited it and believe it is correct now.

Comment: I was thinking something simpler to prove that $|x|^p$ is convex.And that is that it's second derivative is $\geq 0$\begin{align*}
\phi(x) &= |x|^p \\
\phi(x)' &= \dfrac{p\left|x\right|^p}{x} \\
\phi(x)'' &=  \dfrac{\left(p-1\right)p\left|x\right|^p}{x^2} \geq 0 
\end{align*}

Comment: I guess it works for $x\ne 0$. e.g. if p=1, then |x| is convex but you cannot show it using this at x=0 as $lim_{x\rightarrow 0-}\phi'(x)=-1$ but $lim_{x\rightarrow 0+}\phi'(x)=1$

Comment: and $p \in [1,+\infty]$

Comment: you mean the weak derivative? if I set $x\neq 0$ I am fine.